# Warn Users Of Older Browsers That Don't Support New CSS3 Standards

Tags: javascript, redirect, css, cross-browser, browser-detection

I'm trying to redirect older browsers that don't support CSS3 or iFrames to a warning page where I explain that they may experience problems with their older browsers if they continue.

The script (or otherwise) should test for css3 comparability and not browser id.

A banner that displays at the top of the page if the user is viewing using a older browser would also be acceptable.

I'm currently using:
`<!--[if lt IE 9]><div style=' clear: both; height: 200px; padding:0 0 0 15px; position: relative;'><a href="old"><img src="old-browser.jpg" border="0" height="153" width="659" alt="" /></a></div><![endif]-->`

Is their Anyone have any experience with this or a link to an example? Thanks.

Comment: all latest browser support `css3` and `html5`, anyways you can do it by knowing the user's browser and version . google it

Comment: I have googled it and have only found half-complete solutions from 2003-2006! The problem's not the latest browser's, it's the monkeys running around with IE6,7 Firefox 1,2 Safari 1,2,3 ect

Comment: @diEcho css3 and html5 aren't fully defined yet - it's impossible for any browser to fully support them. I would assume that when daba says "support css3" he means to test for specific features.

Comment: Yeah, that comment was better off deleted ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Testing for the browser version is an unreliable method - many users do not provide that information, and others tell you they are using a different browser then they really are. If you need specific features then the only reliable way to determine if they are available is to use javascript to see if they exist.

Are you determined to redirect, not just change what's displayed? Because changing the contents of the current page would be much simpler. Just add something like this to your page:

```
<div id='warning'>Your browser sucks!</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#warning {
  /* make this DIV very visible - you could even cover the rest
     of the page if your website is useless without javascript. */
}
```

Now the page will load with #warning displayed, and you can use javascript to hide it if the required features are present (you don't want to do the inverse and use javascript to display it because you want it displayed if your script doesn't run). There are a lot of ways to do that, and the most "standard" way would be to attach an onload event. However, this is one situation where I think a hackish approach is much better. If you do the test on-load, then the warning will be displayed until the javascript executes, which could be anywhere from a fraction of a second to several seconds. What you really want to do is hide the element before it is ever displayed, and you can do that by adding something like this to the `<head>` section.

```
if((function() {
  var t,u,i,j,
    css='textShadow,textStroke,boxShadow,borderRadius,borderImage,opacity'.split(','),
    prefixes=',webkit,moz,o,ms,khtml'.split(','),
    nPrefixes=prefixes.length,
    el=document.createElement('i').style;
  styles:for(i=0;t=css[i];i++) {
    t=t.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+t.substr(1);
    for(j=0;j<nPrefixes;j++) {
      u=prefixes[j]+t;
      if(el[u.charAt(0).toLowerCase()+u.substr(1)]!==undefined)
        continue styles;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return true;
})())
  document.write("<style type='text/css'>#warning {display:none;}</style>");
```

As per your example, this assumes that the features you need are textShadow, textStroke, boxShadow, borderRadius, borderImage, and opacity.

You really shouldn't put any other javascript in the `<head>` though, since the page won't start rendering until the code above it finishes executing.

Comment: I think putting this in a [`noscript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/noscript) tag is better than using JavaScript to hide it. Also consider not to hide the whole page but just to put the notice somewhere visible, like SO does. Not being able to see the content of a site because of this would be annoying. even if the site may be broken. I'm convinced whoever browses without javascript is doing it on purpose or is forced to do so. Those who use old browsers for other reasons are beyond help anyway.

Comment: There are two problems with noscript, the main one being that the OP doesn't just want to test for javascript support, but for specific feature support. Additionally, the tag is known to make search engines less trusting of your site (thus you rank lower). But you're right about not covering the entire page - I shouldn't have assumed his site would be useless without the features he's testing for. Answer edited.

Comment: Yes, displaying just a banner on the top is fine, So you are saying that I should add code like this: http://jsfiddle.net/h43Uj/ and the code above all into my page head? Won't that cause considerable render delays? Sorry, but I'm a complete JS noob.

Comment: Yes, just modify your code to return true or false instead of printing the results. And yes, it will delay the page rendering, but there's no other way (that I know of) to be sure the warning box never flahes before being hidden. And if your code's not horribly inefficient (doesn't look like it is), and the rest of your javascript runs after the page renders, then the delay will be too short to notice.

Comment: haha, no, that is just code I got from elsewhere, when I say noob, I mean that I have never coded anything in JS... :( Thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: You are right, checking for features is better than just checking for JS. But still: Showing it by default leads to ugly flashing on page load. I would use the noscript tag and additionally show a message (using JS) only if JS is enabled but features aren't available.

Comment: @kapep That's a better approach, but still doesn't address SEO. And as for the flash, I'm well aware of it, and that's why my answer is somewhat convoluted: it avoids the flash, completely. I'm a little proud of it since I made it up :) (though I'm sure somebody else did too)

Comment: @daba ok, good, then I can say that I think that code's ugly :p . I'll modify it for you, just give me a minute.

Comment: I'm currently using: `<!--[if lt IE 9]><div style=' clear: both; height: 200px; padding:0 0 0 15px; position: relative;'><a href="old"><img src="old-browser.jpg" border="0" height="153" width="659" alt="" /></a></div><![endif]-->` and I'm trying to switch this over so that all browsers that don't support css3 see this message.

Comment: Ok, wasn't aware that it's even executed before rendering. I'm just no friend of disabling parts of the page with JS. Even without the noscript, you could set `display:none;` as default and show it with JS. If there really is no flashing though, enabling wouldn't give much advantage over disabling it, other than avoiding the head script maybe (and it being visible to browsers without js and bots of course).

Comment: @kapep I think you're right, having scripts in the head is usually a bad idea - but in this case I don't know of a better solution. Also, if you show it with js instead of disabling it, then it won't show when the user doesn't support js at all.

Comment: @daba ok, answer was updated. So just put everything in the last code block in a script in the head of each document you want to display the warning on, and give your current warning div an id of "warning". You can get rid of the conditional comments, as they can't really be expanded to suite your purpose, and together with the script they're redundant.

Comment: I've found this: http://jsfiddle.net/29Xzx/1/ but won't the `display:none;` still show for searchbots?

Comment: The div's will, and the span's will not. But that solution is a large step backward from what I just put in my post - is what I wrote not what you're looking for?

Comment: @skier88 I've tried it and it seems hide the warning div in ie6, ect. See here for a example: http://dariobauer.com/browser-test.html

Comment: Oh, lol, I don't know why I did that. Just delete the "!" in the if statement at the end. (answer updated)

Comment: Yes, works now. IE9 & FF9 are not compatible with all the CSS3 functions in the test (textStroke & borderImage), so I have removed those two tests. Thanks again! :)

Comment: No problem :) If your question is answered you can accept an answer to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

Grab [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) and make a version with all the features you need.
Open the modernizr file and add something like this

```
if(Modernizr.borderradius && Modernizr.cssgradients && Modernizr.textshadow) { var valid = true; var
expires = new Date(); expires.setDate(expires.getDate() + 31); document.cookie = 'browser=modern;
expires='+expires.toUTCString()+'; path=/'; } else { var valid = false; }
```

Replace the features to test for (i.e. Modernizr.borderradius) I state in the example with your own using modernizr's documentation.
I am adding a cookie to the user if their browsers are compliant so I can filter out showing them the code with php.

Next, add this div and javascript at the top, right under your body tag. The javascipt uses jquery to hide the element, but you can use the other examples shown here to do it just with javascript.

```
<div id="warning_block">
Warning! You are viewing this page in a non compatible browser.
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (valid == false) { $("#warning_block").show(); }
</script>
```

You can include CSS to style it too, so it looks like a warning

```
#warning_block {
display: none;
width: 80%;
border: 1px solid #000;
background: #F00;
color: #FFF;
font-family: arial;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

step 1 - detect your browser version by javascript or by parsing the request header on the server side code.

step 2 - if the version is not supported then redirect to warning page.

(but CSS3 and HTML 5 is not supported widely).

Comment: partially what I want to do, but this doesn't answer anything.